# Partition job configuration using Java config

Tags: spring-batch, partitioner

Please help me how to do Spring batch Partition job using java config. I have to write the partition job based on the account number. I am not sure how to configure the following XML bean in java configuration.

`<int:router input-channel="channel_in" default-output-channel="channel_default" expression="payload.name" ignore-channel-name-resolution-failures="true">
    <int:mapping value="foo" channel="channel_one" />
    <int:mapping value="bar" channel="channel_two" />
</int:router>`

Comment: Without knowing the types of your beans it will be difficult to help. What I can suggest is to follow the remote partitioning sample here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/tree/master/spring-batch-samples#remote-partitioning-sample which uses Java configuration. The code of the sample is here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/tree/master/spring-batch-samples/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/sample/remotepartitioning. I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Mahmoud. I am creating Spring partition job using java config. We already have partition job using XML config. Our goal is to mimic the same with java config. I did partition step and handler using java config, even I configured the channel and aggregator but not sure how to configure the router. Thanks

Comment: You edited the question and removed the xml snippet. Now your question does not make sense anymore: `how to configure the following xml bean in java configuration`.

Comment: I did somewhat like below, Its solve my purpose @Router(inputChannel = "channel_in")
public ExpressionEvaluatingRouter router() {
   ExpressionParser parser = new SpelExpressionParser();
   Expression expression = parser.parseExpression("payload.name");
   ExpressionEvaluatingRouter router = new ExpressionEvaluatingRouter(expression);
   router.setChannelMapping(DirectChannel.class.getName(), "channel_one");
   router.setChannelMapping(DirectChannel.class.getName(), "channel_two");
   return router;
}